# Loading large XML files into XML Notepad

Tags: memory, xml

While loading a 250 MB XML file in Microsoft's [XML Notepad](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=72d6aa49-787d-4118-ba5f-4f30fe913628&displaylang=en), I get an "OutOfMemoryException". Is there any way to increase the size limit?

Is there any other tool that can load large XML files?

Comment: I asked a somewhat similar question over a year ago - you might find something useful there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308679/lightweight-xml-viewer-that-can-handle-large-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editors like [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) or [UltraEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) might help. However I don't have a reply for increasing the memory limit.

Comment: +1 for ultraedit. I've opened multi-gigabyte files in it before. Scrolling long distances is a bit sluggish, but aside from that, it's perfect.

Comment: I can vouch for opening files larger than a gigabyte in N++ too.

Answer (score 0):

Any number of 3rd party text editors will load large files as will Visual Studio (although it gets a bit slow if the XML file are large because of the work its doing to build the document model).

You can also use WordPad which doesn't have the same size limits - but its less than ideal as a text editor.

My text editor of choice is TextPad - but there are a *lot* of choices.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php) (or the GUI counterparts GVim or [Cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/home.html)). Vim uses buffers and never loads the entire file into memory.

Comment: Vim is really great :)

Answer (score 0):

XML Notepad is a .NET application and is marked as "Any CPU" (I have downloaded XML Notepad and checked it with [corflags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28VS.80,printer%29.aspx).).

Thus if you run it on a 64 bit version of Windows with enough RAM then 
the OutOfMemoryException exception should not happen.

---

**Update**: It works! (almost)

I tried it on a 410 MB XML file. Private Bytes went to 6.7 GB before XML Notepad ran out of memory on my 8 GB system. So it is possible to break the 1.4 GB barrier and
the 250 MB XML file can probably be openened.

I also tried to open a 97 MB XML file. XML Notepad did not run out of memory and opened fine. 
Private Bytes was 719 MB.

Answer (score 0):

[XMLMax](http://xponentsoftware.com/xml-editor.aspx) will handle it easily and put it in a treeview in about ten seconds.

> #### What Problems Does XMLMax Solve?
>
> **Too Big.**  If other software, or processes such as ETL, cannot open XML because it is too large, XMLMax will split XML into smaller, well-formed XML files. It provides several split options. Quickly and easily split large sitemap files.Also see our XmlSplit tool.

[image]